# keyCode issue - Can't prevent entering the % character

Tags: javascript, keycode

In my HTML page there is an input text field. I want only number key and left/right arrow on the keyboard can be entered. I tried the following JavaScript but met an issue.

```
<input onkeypress="return allowNumberOnly(event)" />

function allowNumberOnly(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;

    //keyCode 48-57 represent the number 0-9
    //keyCode 37,39 represent the Left and Right arrow
    //keyCode 46 represent the Delete key
    //keyCode 8 represent the Backspace key

    return charCode == 37 || charCode == 39 || charCode == 46 || charCode == 8
              || (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57);
}
```

After testing this code, I found a problem that the keyCode of left arrow and % special character are both 37. So I can't prevent user entering % character meanwhile allowing the Left arrow. I have no idea why this would happen. I always thought the keyCode should be unique for each key on the keyboard. I thought of using onkeyup instead of onkeypress. But the onkeyup would allow user entering the invalid character first, then remove from the input text. This behavior is not what I want. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I debugged the code in FireFox and found the following difference.

**1. If enter %, event.which == 37 and event.keyCode == 0

2. If enter Left Arrow, event.which == 0 and event.keyCode == 37**

The problem seems to be resolved by using this difference. I will continue to try in IE and Chrome.

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gW6k3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Bryant Williams' answer to this question:

[how can i track arrow keys in Chrome and IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226859/how-can-i-track-arrow-keys-in-chrome-and-ie)

He suggests checking if the charCode==0, or checking for the shift key being pressed.

Comment: @Nile Adding the event.shiftKey == false do exclude the % character, but it also prevent me entering the combination key Shift + Left. I'd like to use this combination key to select the content in the input text field.

Answer (score 2):

This link has more info about Keyboard events

http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Also I made jQuery version

```
$('input').keypress( function( e ){ 

    var code = e.which || e.keyCode ; 

    if ( !( e.shiftKey == false &&
            (
               code == 46 ||
               code == 8 ||
               code == 37 ||
               code == 39 ||
               ( code >= 48 && code <= 57 ) 
            )
         )
    ){

         e.preventDefault();                   
    }

});
```

check it on http://jsfiddle.net/UGpUJ/

Comment: I don't think posting a single link to general info about the issue is an adequate answer.

Comment: @CiananSims I made a jQuery solution . Please check updated answer !

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this [a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814323/javascript-keycodes-not-working-in-firefox-but-works-well-in-chrome#11814362):

```
var numbersOnly = function(e){
    var charCode = (typeof e.which === "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode,
        chr = String.fromCharCode(charCode); //convert it to a character

    if(isNaN(parseInt(chr, 10))) e.preventDefault();
}
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" name="phoneNumber" onkeypress="numbersOnly(event);">
```

Basically what we're doing here is getting the key code used, converting that to its char code equivalent, and then testing the char code instead of the key code. I find this method to work much better than any other I've come across and it works pretty nicely.

[JS Bin Example.](http://jsbin.com/ekosop/1/edit)

Comment: The OP also wants to allow `<` and `>` keys (hence the issue with `%`).

Comment: @JaredFarrish Ah, see in Chrome the arrow keys worked, though testing it in Fx I see that they don't.

Comment: I suspect it's because Firefox sees `<` and `%` as [flipped `.keyCode` and `.charCode`](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/mvJD5/1/). Chrome appears to ignore `<` presses.

Comment: Hm.. maybe. It seems very odd. (Sidenote: `<` and `>` made me think you were talking about chevrons, so for future readers: don't think that.)

Comment: @Nile your fiddle works okay in jsbin but its not working in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vnodkumar1987/uhufp/2/  (have added radix parameter)

Comment: @Bingo On the lefthand side of the page click "Frameworks & Extensions", then click on where it says "onLoad" and change it to the  "in <head>" option.

Comment: @Bingo I have absolutely no idea what you're asking, but I'm almost positive it's off topic.

Comment: @NIle I am asking about that <head> option part. how to to do that in file not using that jsfiddle option

Comment: Since when does `fromCharCode` work with key codes, which are not the same thing?

Comment: @ErikE I was under the impression that they were =/. [keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.keyCode) returns a Unicode value, [fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) returns a string created by a Unicode value... check MDN

Comment: @Nile I tested your code both in Chrome and FireFox. In Chrome, the Left/right arrow keys worked, but in FireFox they don't.

Answer (score 0):

Use onKeydown event. For % it is 53.

Check this links for keycode checking: http://kyokodaniel.com/tech/utils/keycodes.html

http://www.west-wind.com/WestwindWebToolkit/samples/Ajax/html5andCss3/keycodechecker.aspx